# Debug Assertion Failed Using Scanf

Tags: c++, debugging, assertion

I'm working on a school project and I have to use the values A and B as ints as well as use %d and %c with scanf. I have to use scanf with disable 4996 to get input however it keeps triggering a debug assertion error and I can't figure it out.

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    printf("enter first value: ");
    scanf("%c", a);

    printf("\nenter second value: ");
    scanf("%d", b);

    printf("%d%d",a,b);




    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  This looks like straight C code

Comment: Change `scanf("%c", a);` to `scanf("%d", &a);`. `scanf("%d", b);` is wrong as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf()` expects to be given the address of the variables it should write to:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
            ^^
```

> I have to use the values A and B as ints as well as use %d and %c with scanf.

You cannot use `%c` with an integer since the format string must match the output parameters in type.

### Standard advice: Don't use `scanf()` in C++.

Comment: It also expects the type of the input specifier to match that of the input variable.

Comment: @NeilButterworth god damnit.

Comment: See why we stopped using this old dog in C++?  Far fewer little surprises when you have functions that can do type checking for you.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm well aware of the unsafety of `scanf()` and also didn't advocate for its use. Using `%c` for an `int` was an error introduced by copy & paste which i would not have made if i had typed the line.

Comment: Not mocking you, Swordfish. You just happened to help a demonstration. One little slip-up and and unless your compiler is kind enough to parse the format string and spit out a warning or two when it sees mis-matched input theGod-Emperor of C++ is up the same creek as the rank n00b.

Comment: @user4581301 "You just happened to help a demonstration." Always glad to be of help ^^